# MacBook Pro takes ~60 seconds to access websites first time via wifi after wake. DNS issue?

Tags: network, wifi, sleep-wake, dns, internet

I have about 4 Windows/Mac laptops all connected to the same router but I'm only experiencing this odd issue with my 2015 15" MacBook Pro:

After waking the computer and successfully connecting to my wifi network, it takes about 50-60 seconds to actually contact the internet/load a website, after which time everything loads in the expected 1-2 seconds. It's just that initial connection, and it's just this one MacBook Pro.

I don't believe it's a wifi connection issue, because the computer connects to the wifi almost immediately and I can access local network shares etc. instantly, it's just this one use case scenario of loading a website or Spotify or Mail or anything else contacting the outside world via the internet.

I wondered if it could be some kind of DNS issue; right now my wifi adapter is set without a custom DNS server so I believe it's just using my router, but the router seems fine and no other device on our network is experiencing this connection delay. I've tried inputting custom DNS servers like Google's 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4 but the problem still persists.

The Ping gives some indication:

Request timeout for icmp_seq 147

Request timeout for icmp_seq 148

Request timeout for icmp_seq 149

64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=148 ttl=58 time=2010.641 ms

64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=149 ttl=58 time=1009.764 ms

64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=150 ttl=58 time=16.569 ms

64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=151 ttl=58 time=14.475 ms

Comment: what is the result of Ping

Comment: Run this in terminal to see what is it doing `sudo tcpdump -i en0
`

Comment: Thanks @Ruskes, sorry if it takes me a while to reply. So I ran that command and tried to load Google Maps, and for the first ~45 seconds nothing came up, but then a bunch of text came up when the page finally loaded, so maybe the 'delay' is somewhere else in my system? I can't paste the resultant text stream here because it's too long...! Unless I'm trying to reply in the wrong place...

Comment: did you try the test with PING, again in Terminal type `Ping 8.8.8.8` Pinging Google, the result should be about 60 milli seconds, use Control C to quit

Comment: Ok, I pinged the DNS server but as before didn't get any responses til after about 150 seconds. You can see it finally contact the server after 'seq 149':  

`Request timeout for icmp_seq 147`  

`Request timeout for icmp_seq 148`  

`Request timeout for icmp_seq 149`  

`64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=148 ttl=58 time=2010.641 ms`  

`64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=149 ttl=58 time=1009.764 ms`  

`64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=150 ttl=58 time=16.569 ms`  

`64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=151 ttl=58 time=14.475 ms`

Comment: p.s. It's so infuriating trying to reply in this little window where I can't format anything correctly....!

Comment: I moved your results to your OP. Since you have 4 computers competing for internet on the Router, try disconnecting the other 3 from Internet and just use the 2015 15" MacBook Pro: to tell you if it is the router

Comment: Thanks; actually I mentioned having 4 computers but I’m only ever using one at a time and only this one gives me this problem so I don’t think it’s the router.

Comment: Lets try Ping only the first jump, that is your router usually at 192.168.1.1 or ....0.1. The result should be 1 or 2 ms

Comment: Thanks, I can ping my router at about 3ms. I've also noticed if I toggle my wifi off/on again during this 'delay', it connects right away, so maybe it's a wifi/network card issue in my Macbook Pro? I found this similar issue:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/118780/wifi-doesnt-work-unless-i-turn-it-off-then-on-again

Comment: Interesting, so it connects to the Router fast, but then it chokes on next step, what is your router model, did you reset it ?

Comment: It's an ASUS RT-AC87R. I haven't tried resetting it because this problem existed before I started using this router, however I have reset some of my old preference files as mentioned in the linked issue so we'll see if that helps anything.

Comment: It is possibly your Airport software on the Mac. Hold Option and click on the WiFi icon on the top, then choose the Create Diagnostic Report, then look at it and also run the Open Wireless diagnostic and follow the instructions

Answer (score 1):

I occasionally encounter similar behavior on my 2022 Mac Studio (Sonoma 14.2.1). These details may help.

The Wi-Fi connectivity issue is limited to Safari (occasionally, Apple Mail will appear offline, too), with Chrome, Edge, etc., sites open as expected. All browsers use the default DNS settings.

If I close Safari (Mail if necessary) and disable Wi-Fi, then access the destination over Ethernet. The site promptly loads using Safari (Mail, too). Now, I can reconnect to Wi-Fi, and everything works as designed.

But I have no Wi-Fi issues on my MacBook Air using Mail or Safari. On both computers, the DNS settings and version of Safari (17.2.21) are identical.

In summary, the connectivity issue is the exception, not the rule. I estimate it occurs on 1/10 sessions (Mail, less frequently). And is limited to Safari.

Comment: Sounds like it merits a visit to bugreporter

Comment: @BitByByte interesting. I've since discovered another small tip, that if I toggle my wifi off/on again during this 'delay', it connects right away, so maybe it's a wifi/network card issue? You might want to try that and see if it helps. There's a similar issue being discussed here:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/118780/wifi-doesnt-work-unless-i-turn-it-off-then-on-again